# SQL column name with function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create 3 new columns with their names reffering to some date varibales and this is not possible to write them like this. So the first column name should be YEAR2022, 2nd column YEAR2021 and 3rd column YEAR2020.

Can you please give me an idea how to write this?

```sql
select column1*2 as CONCAT('YEAR',YEAR(DATEADD(YY,0,GETDATE()))),
        column1*3 as CONCAT('YEAR',YEAR(DATEADD(YY,-1,GETDATE()))),
        column1*4 as CONCAT('YEAR',YEAR(DATEADD(YY,-2,GETDATE()))) FROM table1
```

The error that I get is:

> Incorrect syntax near 'YEAR'.

Comment: An alias **cannot** be an expression, it must be a literal. If you need dynamically named columns this is normally the sign of a design flaw, in my opinion.

Comment: You need to do a dynamic SQL in a for loop instead

Comment: There is no need for a loop here, @Alen.Toma . There are, in fact, *very* few reasons to ever use a `WHILE` loop (T-SQL doesn't support For Loops) in SQL; it is a set based language and set based methods are almost *always* more performant.

Comment: Most report writing tools make this a trivial task - is that an option? And why do you need that complicated dateadd logic? You can simply use the YEAR() function and subtract 1 or 2 from it - far easier to read and understand. Adding or subtracting 0 (zero) from a given value serves no useful purpose.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, an alias **cannot** be an expression, it has to be a literal. As such the expressions you have tried to use are not allowed and generate syntax errors.

Normally, this sort requirement is the sign of a design flaw, or that you're trying to do something that should be in the presentation in the SQL layer. I'm going to assume the latter here. As a result, instead you should use static names for the columns, and then in your presentation layer, control the name of the columns there, so that when they are presented to the end user they have the names you want (for today that would be `YEAR2022`, `YEAR2021` and `YEAR2020`). Then your query would just look like this:

```sql
select column1*2 AS ThisYear,
       column1*3 AS YearPrior,
       column1*4 AS Year2Prior
FROM dbo.table1;
```

How you change the names of the columns in your presentation layer is a completely different question (we don't even know what language you are using to write your application). If you want to ask about that, I suggest asking a new question (only if after you've adequately researched the problem and failed to find a solution), so that we can help you there.

Note that Though you can achieve a solution via dynamic SQL, I would strongly suggest it is the *wrong* solution here, and thus why I haven't given an answer providing a demonstration.